# Google drive web hosting

Tags: web, google-drive-api

I want to host a sample website in drive.

It has layout page, css, JS & images (this one in a sub folder).

When I preview the main/layout page,

1. I don't see the other pages (supposed to be imported in it)
2. No style, no visible images

I had followed the steps as per this 
[Reference Link](http://www.codeitpretty.com/2013/03/how-to-host-website-on-google-drive.html)

Is there any other way to *host* the site which will work in my case?

Comment: How do you give references to the styles and images?

Comment: by using relative urls like normally done

Comment: Like this..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, instead `.htm` I converted them and used `.html` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive can only be used to host image assets (png, gif, jpg) that are referenced in a dynamic feed (Google Spreadsheet or csv file).

It cannot be used to host static websites as it was earlier (from august 2014 Google has stopped this service).

For more info https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/4351301?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If your directory's `id` is ABC123 and your images are under `images` folder under ABC123, your images are available under

```
https://googledrive.com/host/ABC123/images/image1.png
```

Official docs about website publishing is on https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used relative url (images/image1.png) only and it works fine, the issue was apparently file extension

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host a static website in Google Drive, there is a service that helps you to do it.

You can put the website files in your Google Drive, and then go to [http:/gweb.io/](http://gweb.io), add a domain to your Google Drive folder, point the DNS records as indicated by gweb and that's it.

You can use a custom domain if you have one or a gweb subdomain. 
Make sure to have an index.html file for your website's homepage.