# Google Drive CSS/JS Returns 404 Error

Tags: css, google-drive-api, hosting

I hosted my CSS/JS on Google Drive.
But it suddenly stopped working (tested on Chrome, Safari, Mac, iPhone..).
Upon inspecting with `Chrome`, I saw that the link to Google Drive [returned a 404](https://googledrive.com/host/0B3X3aqxEWs4QY3BoLW1VS0FvRU0).

Anyone else had that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Drive Web Hosting is now deprecated.
That goes for both CSS *and* JS, and no matter what link format you use (host, id, view, etc.).

Any CSS or JS you have on Google Drive, linked to a website, will no longer work (even if it was all setup - and working - before this deprecation came about).
For example (I tested this myself repeatedly), CSS won't load, and upon inspecting your site, you'll see that the Drive link your stuff is supposed to be on, [returns a 404](https://googledrive.com/host//0B3X3aqxEWs4QTzRqWldLODRYb1U/).

In Google's own words:

> Beginning **August 31st, 2015**, web hosting in Google Drive for users and developers will be **deprecated**.
>   You can continue to use this feature for a period of one year until **August 31st, 2016**, when we will discontinue serving content via googledrive.com/host/[doc id].

Source: [gsuite-developers.googleblog.com](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)
Suggested link (from above page): https://cloud.google.com/storage/