# CSS Stylesheet in Google Drive no longer works

Tags: css, google-apps-script, stylesheet, drive

I use the following link to reference a stylesheet used to format a form used to capture data within Google Sheets :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B7atn1EVYAVicjQtV2xTam1odWs/style.css">
```

This used to work without problems, but now suddenly this no longer works? What changed? Isn't it possible anymore to reference a stylesheet that is in Google Drive?

Comment: looks like it was removed. is it yours?

Comment: style.css is in your own drive account?

Comment: as the answer suggested, web hosting from Google Drive is not allowed anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive CSS Returns 404 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-css-returns-404-error)

Answer (score 1):

Hasn't this facility been deprecated?

https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html?m=1